# For any two vectors not on the same line $u,v$, there exists $(I + ab^T)u = v$ where $a^Tb = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove for any two vectors not on the same line $u,v$ (i.e. you can't write $u = kv$ where $k$ is a constant) exists $(I + ab^T)u = v$ where $a^Tb = 0$. Here $a, b, u, v$ are all $n$ dimensional vectors and $I$ is an $n \times n$ identtiy matrix.

I struggle a bit to express $ab^T$. One can say $ab^T$'s eigenvalues are all 0's, but how does that help?

$(I + ab^T)$ also looks like a special geometric transformation, but I struggle to find any inspiration for the proof.

Comment: $ab^{T}$ reminds me about an orthogonal projection matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $u,v\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ are linearly independent, it follows easily that $u,v-u\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ are also linearly independent, implying the column space of the $2\times n$ matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}u^T&-\\ (v-u)^T&-\end{pmatrix}$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. That being said, take $a=v-u$, and let $b$ to be any solution to the system $Ax=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$. We have that $b^Tu=u^Tb=1,a^Tb=(v-u)^Tb=0$, and so $$(I+ab^T)u=u+ab^Tu=u+(v-u)=v$$